# Python function to run at a datetime that was passed to it

Tags: python, datetime, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

There are numerous SO answers that show how to run a scheduler at a specific predefined time. However, I am curious to know how to make a function run at a certain time (that changes every time).

Current code:

```
@blueprint.route("/notifications", methods=['POST']) 
def notifications():
    """
    webhook that receives new expiry date everytime
    """
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    expiryDate = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=randint(1,50))
    scheduler(expiryDate)

def scheduler(expiryDate):
        import sched
        scheduler = sched.scheduler(expiryDate)
        scheduler.enter(0, 1, activateChannel()) #0 delay, priority 1
        scheduler.run()
        logging.warning("scheduler called")

def activateChannel():
    return "Hello world"
```

However, the problem with this code is that instead of scheduler getting called in at the expiry date, it gets called immediately. At the same time, I can't take scheduler outside the function as it need the expiry date that changes every time.

P.S: I can't put a delay for

Comment: I used time.sleep in a thread (before you call the desired function) it worked for me. I am not clear how precise its time keeping is.

Comment: Got it. But would time.sleep() be reseted/cancelled if the function changes aka another independent function gets called meanwhile? cause the expiry date is going to be after days & not minutes or seconds & hence the sleep would be for days.

Comment: That's why a dedicated thread to sleep and run the function while your main thread can keep its job done. Sleeping can be as long as you want. You can also sleep shorter period to check any update